# Update field after changing its value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to simulate user input on a website using JavaScript. To do so, I simply do something like this:

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName('field-name')[0];
a.value = 'new value';
```

However, on some websites which require you to click "Send" after the input, the button remains inactive (sorry for not providing the example, the only sites with that feature that I know of require logging in).

I remember that I once fixed that problem by "Updating" the element afterwards, but I don't remember exactly how. I have tried adding this:

```
const change = new InputEvent('change');
a.value = 'new value';
const isNotCancelled = a.dispatchEvent(change);
```

But no luck here. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Update: Just as an example: [here](https://www.livechat.com/) is a website which does what I described. Just click the chat icon on the bottom right and input random stuff for email and etc., then you will see the input box with the button that I described.

Comment: Please create a snippet of your attempt, rather than little code samples with no context.

Comment: by experience I can tell that probably you need to just trigger the `blur` event for the field you mean to "update". That's the event triggering when the input control loses focus and that's what the developer listens to. I did already some browser addon using that strategy to update the fields I meant to fill automatically. Maybe the button remained inactive just because the validation routine wasn't invoked (because you are missing the blur event). Anyway you can control anything including forcing to enable the button or even submit any form

Comment: Even if the button remains inactive you should be able to find it with the querySelector and use the element.click() function (?)

Comment: Maybe you need to trigger a click on the textinput before writing inside of it? Or just remove the `disabled` attribute from the button and trigger a click on the button

Comment: *"Update: Here is a website which does what I described...."* Questions on SO must be stand-alone, they can't rely on off-site content. Three reasons: 1. Some sites are blocked for some users; 2. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to others in the future; and 3. Users shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. If you have a site (or set of sites, apparently) that have this problem, figure out what's common about them and put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`InputEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/InputEvent)'s type should be either `beforeinput` or `input` (`input`, in your case), not `change`; you might also consider firing a an `Event` at it with `type` set to `"change"` (there is no specific `ChangeEvent` constructor). For the `input` event, be sure you set `bubbles: true` since the default for the constructor is `false` but `input` events bubble (`change` events don't, although some libraries make them do so). You might also need to `blur` the field, and you might `focus` it at the start (so the `blur` does something).

For instance:

```
const a = document.getElementsByClassName("field-name")[0];
// Or: const a = document.querySelector(".field-name");
a.focus();
a.value = "new value";
a.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent("input", {bubbles: true, cancelable: true}));
a.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", {bubbles: false, cancelable: true}));
a.blur();
```

As [epascarello suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72951710/update-field-after-changing-its-value-with-javascript/72951776?noredirect=1#comment128861688_72951776), you might also try [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) with the types `keydown`, `keyup`, and/or `keypress`, but then you get into having to set properties like `key` and `code` and repeating them for each character (or perhaps just the last); for maximum compatibility with older code, you'd also have to supply the deprecated `which`, `keyCode`, and `charCode`. It quickly becomes non-trivial.

Alternatively, you might take a non-keyboard approach and send a [`ClipboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) with type `paste`.

If none of those work, find the button and set its `disabled` to `false`.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, but unfortunately none of them worked. I believe that the button is controled by some other script because it is done as follows: ```<button class="Btn Btn--primary Composer-sendBtn" type="button" disabled="">Отправить</button>``` , and the ```disabled``` parameter "vanishes" as I do inputs from the keyboard. I will update the page now to add an example websie which dose the same way, but doesn't require registration.

Comment: @user9102437 - Well, the *"If none of those work, find the button and set its `disabled` to `false`."* would presumably work. :-D (`document.querySelector("selector for the button").disabled = false;`)

Comment: maybe they listen for a key up, down, or press event.